# Method to sort an array relative to another array already sorted in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to make a `String[]` sort to the same order as an `int[]`, (which is greatest to least) using the following code:

```
public static int[] initsNew(int[] inits) {

    Arrays.sort(inits);
    int[] inits1 = new int[inits.length];

    for (int i = 0; i != inits.length; i++) {
        inits1[i] = inits[inits.length - (i + 1)];
        System.out.println(inits1[i]);
    }

    return inits;


}

public static String[] charsNew(String[] chars, int[] inits, int[] initsNew) {
    String[] chars1 = new String[chars.length];
    boolean test = false;
    for (int i = 0; i != chars.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j!= chars.length && test == false; j++) {
            int k = 0;
            if (initsNew[j] == inits[k]) {
                test = true;
                chars1[j] = chars[k];
            } else {
                test = false;
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i != chars.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(chars1[i]);
    }
    return chars1;
}
```

But all I get in the console when I give the values (20, 14, 16, rox, eld, mir) is:

```
16
14
0
rox
null
null
```

What am I doing wrong? It should print out:

```
20
16
14
rox
mir
eld
```

Comment: What is the values of `chars`? of `inits`? of `initsNew`? Post a [reprex], something we could copy, paste, and run as is and get *the same results you are getting*.

Comment: `chars` and `inits` were just scanned arrays, both of length `[3]`. It can be whatever you think it should be fed, but relative to what I input it should print out the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong, but unlike other times people figure their problem out, I'm going to explain exactly what I did wrong and how I solved the problem.
My method array was written like this:

```
public static String[] charsNew(String[] chars, int[] inits, int[] initsNew) {
    String[] chars1 = new String[chars.length];
    boolean test = false;
    for (int i = 0; i != chars.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j!= chars.length && test == false; j++) {
            int k = 0;
            if (initsNew[j] == inits[k]) {
                test = true;
                chars1[j] = chars[k];
            } else {
                test = false;
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println(k);
        }
    }
    return chars1;
}
```

I realized that I was placing a loop `boolean` in the wrong loop test parameter. (I don't know exactly what they're called, don't go off on me, it's the thing right after the term `for` or `while` that contains the `boolean` that requires to be true) I was missing a `while` loop in the sorting algorithm's testing for a position in the array.

My new code is right here:

```
public static String[] charsNew(String[] chars, int[] inits, int[] initsNew) {
    String[] chars1 = new String[chars.length];
    boolean test = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        test = false;
        int k = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
            test = false;
            while (test == false) {
                if (initsNew[j] == inits[k]) {
                    test = true;
                    chars1[j] = chars[k];
                    System.out.println(chars1[k]);
                    System.out.println(k);
                    k = 0;
                } else {
                    test = false;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return chars1;
}
```

But thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

This code will order in descent both arrays of string and primitive int

```
    final String[] arrayOfStrings = {"abc", "bdc", "ced", "bcd", "cde"};
    final int[] arrayOfPrimitiveInt = {1,6,2,8,4,6,3};
    Integer[] arrayOfIntegers= new Integer[arrayOfPrimitiveInt.length];
    for(int i=0; i < arrayOfPrimitiveInt.length; i++) {
        arrayOfIntegers[i] = arrayOfPrimitiveInt[i];
    }
    Arrays.sort(arrayOfStrings, Collections.reverseOrder());
    Arrays.sort(arrayOfIntegers, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Does the `String[]` sort to the order of the integers?

Comment: @user3482676 String[] is just the type declaration, the sorting is done by Arrays.sort(). I separated them for two reason, the first is that you can read it more easily and rework it as you see fit, the second is more important: Arrays.sort(x, Collections.reverseOrder()) will not sort int(primitive), it accepts only objects, thats why im maping the primitives to new array of Integers (objects) and then sorting. Hope it makes sence